# R: How to sum across multiple columns with varying window size?

Tags: r

Here's an illustrative dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
sam_dat <- data.frame(
  Operator = seq(1:3),
  t1 = sample(runif(10)*10, 3),
  t2 = sample(runif(3)*10, 3),
  t3 = sample(runif(12)*10, 3),
  t4 = sample(runif(34)*10, 3)
)
```

What would is the easiest way calculating the following (tidyverse, base R, or other)?

```
t1_t2 = t1 + t2
t1_t3 = t1 + t2 + t3
t1_t4 = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
```

***edit***
Is there a way to do this without having to explicitly write out each calculation?  While that is feasible for the four columns in my example dataset, my real data has many more.

By manual calculation, the result for Operator 1 would be:

```
10.71,  19.40,  20.48
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `transform`

```
transform(sam_dat, t1_t2 = t1 + t2, 
          t1_t3 = t1 + t2 + t3, t1_t4 = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4)
#  Operator       t1       t2       t3       t4     t1_t2    t1_t3    t1_t4
#1        1 5.728534 4.976992 8.696908 1.079436 10.705526 19.40243 20.48187
#2        2 2.655087 7.176185 9.347052 7.829328  9.831272 19.17832 27.00765
#3        3 2.016819 7.698414 1.255551 4.068302  9.715234 10.97078 15.03909
```

---

Or another option is to subset the dataset into a `list` and then use `rowSums`

```
sam_dat[c("t1_t2", "t1_t3", "t1_t4")] <- sapply(list(sam_dat[c('t1', 't2')], 
       sam_dat[c('t1', 't2', 't3')], 
          sam_dat[c('t1', 't2', 't3', 't4')]), rowSums)
```

---

Or make it more compact with indexing

```
nm1 <- paste(names(sam_dat)[2], names(sam_dat)[3:5], sep="_")
sam_dat[nm1] <- sapply(3:5, function(i) rowSums(sam_dat[2:i]))
```

---

Or another option is `rowCumsums` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
sam_dat[nm1] <- rowCumsums(as.matrix(sam_dat[-1]))[,-1]
```

---

Or a `base R` operation similar to `accumulate` from `purrr` is `Reduce`

```
sam_dat[nm1] <- do.call(cbind, Reduce(`+`, sam_dat[-1], accumulate = TRUE)[-1])
```

---

Or with `mutate` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
sam_dat %>%
  mutate(t1_t2 = t1 + t2, 
         t1_t3 = t1 + t2 + t3,
         t1_t4 = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4)
```

---

Or another option in `tidyverse` would be to pivot to 'long' format, do the computation and then transform back to 'wide'

```
 library(tidyr)
 library(stringr)
 sam_dat %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -Operator) %>%
     group_by(Operator) %>%
     mutate(value = cumsum(value)) %>% 
     slice(-1) %>%
     ungroup %>% 
     mutate(name = str_c('t1_', name)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
    select(-Operator) %>% 
    bind_cols(sam_dat, .)
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  Operator    t1    t2    t3    t4 t1_t2 t1_t3 t1_t4
#     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1        1  5.73  4.98  8.70  1.08 10.7   19.4  20.5
#2        2  2.66  7.18  9.35  7.83  9.83  19.2  27.0
#3        3  2.02  7.70  1.26  4.07  9.72  11.0  15.0
```

Comment: Thanks for providing so many ways to do this.  Each one is a good lesson.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `rowwise` function in dplyr

```
sam_dat[-1]%>%
    rowwise()%>%
    do(setNames(data.frame(t(cumsum(unlist(.)))),sprintf('t1_%s',names(.)))[-1])%>%
    cbind(sam_dat,.)
  Operator       t1       t2       t3       t4     t1_t2    t1_t3    t1_t4
1        1 5.728534 4.976992 8.696908 1.079436 10.705526 19.40243 20.48187
2        2 2.655087 7.176185 9.347052 7.829328  9.831272 19.17832 27.00765
3        3 2.016819 7.698414 1.255551 4.068302  9.715234 10.97078 15.03909
```

The basic operation being:

```
sam_dat[-1]%>%
    rowwise()%>%
     do(data.frame(t(cumsum(unlist(.)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `apply` + `cumsum`, i.e.,

```
sam_dat <- cbind(sam_dat,
                 `colnames<-`(t(apply(sam_dat[-1], 1,cumsum))[,-1],
                              paste0("t1_",names(sam_dat)[-c(1,2)])))
```

such that

```
> sam_dat
  Operator       t1       t2       t3       t4     t1_t2    t1_t3    t1_t4
1        1 5.728534 4.976992 8.696908 1.079436 10.705526 19.40243 20.48187
2        2 2.655087 7.176185 9.347052 7.829328  9.831272 19.17832 27.00765
3        3 2.016819 7.698414 1.255551 4.068302  9.715234 10.97078 15.03909
```

Comment: you beat me by 4 seconds!! was almost clicking on post!

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
map(.x = accumulate(names(sam_dat[-1]), c)[-1], 
    ~ sam_dat %>%
     mutate(!!paste(.x, collapse = "_") := rowSums(select(., one_of(.x))))) %>%
 reduce(full_join)

  Operator       t1       t2        t3       t4    t1_t2 t1_t2_t3 t1_t2_t3_t4
1        1 5.728534 4.976992 0.1339033 7.942399 10.70553 10.83943    18.78183
2        2 3.721239 7.698414 2.6722067 4.590657 11.41965 14.09186    18.68252
3        3 8.983897 3.841037 9.3470523 5.297196 12.82493 22.17199    27.46918
```

Or to further match your desired output:

```
map(.x = accumulate(names(sam_dat[-1]), c)[-1], 
    ~ sam_dat %>%
     mutate(!!paste(head(.x, 1), tail(.x, 1), sep = "_") := rowSums(select(., one_of(.x))))) %>%
 reduce(full_join)

  Operator       t1       t2        t3       t4    t1_t2    t1_t3    t1_t4
1        1 5.728534 4.976992 0.1339033 7.942399 10.70553 10.83943 18.78183
2        2 3.721239 7.698414 2.6722067 4.590657 11.41965 14.09186 18.68252
3        3 8.983897 3.841037 9.3470523 5.297196 12.82493 22.17199 27.46918
```